# Golang Hide XML parent tag if empty

Tags: xml, go, marshalling

After some trail and error I'd like to share the issue I am dealing with.

I'm populating an struct and convert it to an XML ( xml.Marshal ) 
As you can see below the Foo example works as expected. The Bar example however creates an empty group1.

So my question is : "How do I prevent Group1 to be generated if there are no children set."

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

type Example1 struct{
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"Example1"`
    Element1 string   `xml:"Group1>Element1,omitempty"`
    Element2 string   `xml:"Group1>Element2,omitempty"`
    Element3 string   `xml:"Group2>Example3,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    foo := &Example1{}
    foo.Element1 = "Value1" 
    foo.Element2 = "Value2" 
    foo.Element3 = "Value3" 

    fooOut, _ := xml.Marshal(foo)
    fmt.Println( string(fooOut) )

    bar  := &Example1{}
    bar.Element3 = "Value3"
    barOut, _ := xml.Marshal(bar)
    fmt.Println( string(barOut) )
}
```

Foo Output :

```
<Example1>
    <Group1>
        <Element1>Value1</Element1>
        <Element2>Value2</Element2>
    </Group1>
    <Group2>
        <Example3>Value3</Example3>
    </Group2>
</Example1>
```

Bar Output :

```
<Example1>
    <Group1></Group1>  <------ How to remove the empty parent value ? 
    <Group2>
        <Example3>Value3</Example3>
    </Group2>
</Example1>
```

**Addition**

Additionally i have tried doing the following, but still generates an empty "Group1":

```
type Example2 struct{
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"Example2"`
    Group1   struct{
        XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"Group1,omitempty"`
        Element1 string   `xml:"Element1,omitempty"`
        Element2 string   `xml:"Element2,omitempty"`
    }
    Element3 string   `xml:"Group2>Example3,omitempty"`
}
```

The full code can be found here : http://play.golang.org/p/SHIcBHoLCG . example to

**EDIT** : Changed the golang example to use MarshalIndent for readability

**Edit 2** The example from Ainar-G Works good for hiding the empty parent, but Populating it makes it a lot harder.  "`panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Example1` doesn't work because apparently the `,omitempty` tag only works on the element itself and not the `a>b>c` enclosing elements.

`Example2` doesn't work because `,omitempty` doesn't recognise empty structs as empty. [From the doc](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal):

> The empty values are false, 0, any nil pointer or interface value, and any array, slice, map, or string of length zero.

No mention of structs. You can make the `baz` example work by changing `Group1` to a pointer to a struct:

```
type Example2 struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"Example1"`
    Group1   *Group1
    Element3 string `xml:"Group2>Example3,omitempty"`
}

type Group1 struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"Group1,omitempty"`
    Element1 string   `xml:"Element1,omitempty"`
    Element2 string   `xml:"Element2,omitempty"`
}
```

Then, if you want to fill `Group1`, you'll need to allocate it separately:

```
foo.Group1 = &Group1{
    Element1: "Value1",
}
```

Example: http://play.golang.org/p/mgpI4OsHf7

Comment: Could you explain why it works with an pointer ? Cant find any reference in the docs about this.

Comment: Now when I try to populate the struct I get the following : `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` any workaround on that ?

Comment: @DonSeba I've given [the link](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal) in my answer. `,omitempty` works for anything but structs. I don't know the exact reason, I guess it has something to do with the limitations of reflection in Go.

Comment: @DonSeba You'll need to allocate the inner struct separately. See edit.

Comment: @Ainar-G not every hero wear capes, thanks!